# JComboBox staying open

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have written a GUI which has many different JComboBoxes.  All of them work as I would expect (I click on them, the popup appears, I click on my selection, and the popup closes).

All of them, that is, except for one.

I have looked at my code, and I am using this combo box in the same way as I am using others.  I am sure that there is something that I am missing, but I do not know what.

I do not know where to start. What kind of thing should I look at in my code to figure this out? If you were to try to achieve this, what would you do, this info might help.

---

As a code sample, I have not done anything out of the ordinary:

```
JComboBox selectionBox = new JComboBox();
selectionBox.addItem(DEFAULT_SELECTION);
selectionBox.addItem("Option1");
selectionBox.addItem("Option2");
selectionBox.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: `I do not know where to start.` - Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. While creating your SSCCE you will probably find the problem.

Comment: Are you debugging? Debugging may reveal where the problem is. Without further information, it's a bit hard to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: just delete it and recreate, the mistake you did probably won't happens twice... also, if you share your code we'll have a look

Comment: idk if this is in your code, but you seem to be missing a ';' on the last line. It might just be my pickiness ;)

Comment: Just a wild guess, maybe it could have something with long running - blocking task in action listener?

Answer (score 0):

Although I understand that it isn't always possible to give a lot of details, an exact answer just isn't possible without more exact information.

That said, I think the best course of action is to examine the code very carefully and make sure that an error cannot be found that could be causing the JComboBox to stay open.

As a LAST resort, you may be able to fix the problem by using [JComboBox's hidePopup() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#hidePopup()) to manually close out of the JComboBox:

```
yourComboBox.hidePopup();
```

P.S. As for not knowing where to start ... if, in general, you're having trouble finding errors in your code, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be a good place for that sort of question.